# Compile py-fast-rcnn using Cmake and met "Link error" when "make runtest"

Tags: gcc, cmake, caffe

```
Linking CXX executable ../../../test/test.testbin
CMakeFiles/test.testbin.dir/test_benchmark.cpp.o: In function `void boost::this_thread::sleep<boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000l> >(boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000l> const&)':
test_benchmark.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11this_thread5sleepINS_9date_time18subsecond_durationINS_10posix_time13time_durationELl1000EEEEEvRKT_[_ZN5boost11this_thread5sleepINS_9date_time18subsecond_durationINS_10posix_time13time_durationELl1000EEEEEvRKT_]+0x27d): undefined reference to `boost::this_thread::hidden::sleep_until(timespec const&)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [test/test.testbin] Error 1
make[2]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/test.testbin.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [src/caffe/test/CMakeFiles/runtest.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [runtest] Error 2
[rbao@ml-01 build]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

This error appears at the last steps of Cmake compilation for py-fast-rcnn when I "make runtest". It looks like a linker problem but I don't know how to fix it. My guess is the version of gcc boost may be incompatible.

Comment: Mine gets to execution on CentOS 7, but hits a memory fault in InfogainLossLayerTest.  The big question is whether you need the tests to run?  I have been fine once I can get l and GoogLeNet to run a few iterations each.

Comment: Seems I haven't got "runtest" compiled successfully, which is required for running demo.py.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that you need that.  I'm afraid I won't be of much help, as I don't have a system on which to even reproduce the problem.  It's pretty hard to debug a crash with no error message.  You might try "ldd" on the nearby objects to see whether there's a missing file or version inconsistency.  Other than that, the best I can suggest is to post this to the GitHub Caffe bugs forum.

Comment: Thanks anyway, I've got the test running. It seems some dependences disruption due to Anaconda.

Comment: Good to know.  Please either post the solution and accept it, or delete the question.  This retires the issue properly in the Stack Overflow archives.

Comment: Thanks for reminding!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by remove the Anaconda, seems Anaconda has some disruption upon my manually set dependencies.